# iOS versions on device do not match supported versions by Xcode

Tags: xcode, ios

When I connect my iPod to MacBook I get this dialog window:

[image: this dialog window]

Comment: That's strange :) ... 4.2.1 vs 4.2.1 :) ... restart maybe ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that reinstalling Xcode helped fix the problem.